# `webkit-box` changing height of element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an endless scrollable row, to display info items.

I have set it up as per below and it's making the item the same size as the holder. I've tried using inline-block but that displays the items in one column:

UPDATE:
the link is the is the element that need to appear at the bottom of the item, i've tried positioning absolute this removes the a tag from item completely. i have also tired vertical align:bottom to no effect.

any help is much appreciated.

```css
.holder {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: visible;
  height: 550px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
.item_row {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.item {
  width: 300px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="item_row">
    <div class="item">
      <!-- Info --> 

<a href="#" class=""> need to appear at bottom </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `display: -webkit-inline-box;`?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: No, Anselm, i don't want to use `display: -webkit-inline-box;` but as I have stated in my question `display:inline-block;` wasn't working. updated.

Comment: `position: absolute` should work if you set the parent element to have `position: relative`. (But that also depends on the rest of the content in the parent element.)

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution for now. If you dont have content in the item why the link goes to bottom. -webkit--inline-box work only chrome thats why i have add two extra display in your .item-row class 
Happy coding enjoy and good luck

```css
.holder {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: visible;
  height: 550px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
.item_row {
   display: -webkit-inline-box;
    display: -moz-inline-box;
   display: -ms-inline-box;
   list-style: none;
   padding: 0;
  }
.item {
  width: 300px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px; 
}


<body>
 <div class="holder">
  <div class="item_row">
    <div class="item">
  <!-- Info --> 
   <img src="http://cdn.online-convert.com/images/image-converter.png"    
    alt="test">
    <h1>test</h1>
    <p>test</p>
   <p>test</p>
   <a href="#" class=""> need to appear at bottom </a>
 </div>
<div class="item">
  <!-- Info --> 
 <img src="http://cdn.online-convert.com/images/image-converter.png"
     alt="test">
    <h1>test</h1>
     <p>test</p>
     <p>test</p>
       <a href="#" class=""> need to appear at bottom </a>
     </div>

   </div>

 </div>

</body>
```